# Unix Epoche value mismatch between datetime and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, epoch

I am storing datetime objects without timezone information in a pandas dataframe.
When retrieving the timestamp information, the timestamp is different compared to the one obtained from the original datetime object.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()
print(dt)
print(dt.timestamp())

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(dt)],columns=["date"])
print(df)

epoche_from_pandas = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.timestamp()).values[0]
print(epoche_from_pandas)
```

Printing the pandas dataframe shows the same datetime string but the epoch value is different. Both timestamps are shifted by 3600 seconds which is equivalent to my local timezone difference (+1 hour).

> 2020-03-20 01:05:05.457290
>
> 1584662705.45729
>
> 2020-03-20 01:05:05.457290
>
> 1584666305.45729

My assumption is that pandas uses its own internal representation which ignores the epoch value (maybe created using the year, month, day, hour... components) and prints in unix time (not localized). This would mean while both print statements result in the same string, the pandas time is actually 1 hour ahead because it reflects unix which usually lags 1 hour behind.

Is the above correct?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? As an aside, why the `.values[0]` ?

Comment: Sure, I added the imports. I use the .values[0] to extract the raw value from the dataframe (it only contains one value, hence the 0th indice.

Comment: As of (I believe) Pandas 1.0, the recommend way of getting a NumPy array from a Series or DataFrame is to use `.to_numpy()`, not `.values`. In any case, you don't even need `.values` here, you can index the Series directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [to_pydatetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html#pandas-series-dt-to-pydatetime) converts the data to a python datetime object and then `timestamp()` returns the same value.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.now()
print(dt)
print(dt.timestamp())

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(dt)],columns=["date"])
print(df)

epoche_from_pandas = df.date.apply(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime().timestamp()).values[0]
print(epoche_from_pandas)
```

Results:

```
2020-03-19 21:20:56.633482
1584667256.633482
                        date
0 2020-03-19 21:20:56.633482
1584667256.633482
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Do you also have details on what causes the difference? Is the assumption I made right?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't technically a solution to the problem yet, but I have found a clearer piece of code which seems to replicate the issue:

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

dt = datetime.now()
print(f"dt: {dt}")
print(f"dt timestamp: {dt.timestamp()}\n")

pd_ts = pd.Timestamp(dt)
print(f"pd Ts: {pd_ts}")
print(f"pd Ts .timestamp(): {pd_ts.timestamp()}")

print(dt.timestamp() - pd_ts.timestamp())
```

Output:

```
dt: 2020-03-19 21:06:12.627798
dt timestamp: 1584666372.627798

pd Ts: 2020-03-19 21:06:12.627798
pd Ts .timestamp(): 1584651972.627798
14400.0
```